# C++ how to output \"\"' (these 5 characters)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string s = "?????";
    std::cout << s << std::flush;
}
```

What should I write in the s variable to output `\"\"'` (these 5 characters?)

Comment: Why close and donvotes?!? The question is perfectly on topic for [tag:c++] and shows a valid code sample!

Answer (score 5):

Escape them like this (prepend `\` to each of the special characters):

```
"\\\"\\\"'"
```

The other option is C++11 raw string literal:

```
R"(\"\"')"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\` and `"` characters with `\`

```
std::string s = "\\\"\\\"'";
```

In C++11, you can also use a raw string literal

```
R"(\"\"')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11, you can put whatever characters you like in a raw string literal:

```
R"(\"\"')"
```

Historically, you would have to escape `\` and `"` with `\` in a normal string literal:

```
"\\\"\\\"'"
```